# Shuffling string (non-randomly) for maximal difference

Tags: r, string, shuffle

After trying for an embarrassingly long time and extensive searches online, I come to you with a problem.

I am looking for a method to (non-randomly) shuffle a string to get a string which has the maximal ‘distance’ from the original one, while still containing the same set of characters.

My particular case is for short nucleotide sequences (4-8 nt long), as represented by these example sequences:

```
seq_1<-"ACTG"
seq_2<-"ATGTT"
seq_3<-"ACGTGCT"
```

For each sequence, I would like to get a scramble sequence which contains the same nucleobase count, but in a different order.

A favourable scramble sequence for seq_3 could be something like;

```
seq_3.scramble<-"CATGTGC"
```

,where none of the sequence positions 1-7 has the same nucleobase, but the overall nucleobase count is the same (A =1, C = 2, G= 2, T=2).  Naturally it would not always be possible to get a completely different string, but these I would just flag in the output.

I am not particularly interested in randomising the sequence and would prefer a method which makes these scramble sequences in a consistent manner.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: do you have to use r?  Can you rigorously define your distance metric? This is basically array manipulation and a couple of for loops.

Comment: If you sequences are too long for doing every permutation you could try several random runs to maximize the distance

Comment: Are you looking for the exact optimal solution or suboptimal solutions are also fine? Also you should define distance metrics as it was mentioned above. For example is [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) acceptable for you?

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone.

To clarify; I have to use R only in as much as it is the tool I am already using for my data analysis.  I am (pain)fully aware that R is not optimal for text manipulation!

The distance metrics I had in mind was a simple number of mismatches to the original sequence, with the optimal being number of mismatches = length of sequence.

Answer (score 1):

python, since I don't know r, but the basic solution is as follows

```
def calcDistance(originalString,newString):
    d = 0
    i=0
    while i < len(originalString):
        if originalString[i] != newString[i]: d=d+1
        i=i+1


s = "ACTG"
d_max = 0
s_final = ""
for combo in itertools.permutations(s):
    if calcDistance(s,combo) > d_max:
            d_max = calcDistance(s,combo)
            s_final = combo
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Mohammad.

I am not sure that it would translate well in to R, as doing permutations inside a **while** or **for** loop might get slow (correct me anyone, if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. Rather than return a single string that fits your criteria, I return a data frame of all strings sorted by their string-distance score. String-distance score is calculated using `stringdist(..., ..., method=hamming)`, which determines number of substitutions required to convert string A to B.

```
seq_3<-"ACGTGCT"

myfun <- function(S) {
            require(combinat)
            require(dplyr)
            require(stringdist)
            vec <- unlist(strsplit(S, ""))
            P <- sapply(permn(vec), function(i) paste(i, collapse=""))
            Dist <- c(stringdist(S, P, method="hamming"))
            df <- data.frame(seq = P, HD = Dist, fixed=TRUE) %>%
                    distinct(seq, HD) %>%
                    arrange(desc(HD))
            return(df)
        }

library(combinat)
library(dplyr)
library(stringdist)
head(myfun(seq_3), 10)

       # seq HD
# 1  TACGTGC  7
# 2  TACGCTG  7
# 3  CACGTTG  7
# 4  GACGTTC  7
# 5  CGACTTG  7
# 6  CGTACTG  7
# 7  TGCACTG  7
# 8  GTCACTG  7
# 9  GACCTTG  7
# 10 GATCCTG  7
```

Comment: Thank you, CPak!

This works perfectly for me.  I can always add methods to choose a particular solution as the best an return only that.